# Organising JMeter API tests

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

I'm pretty new to performance testing.

I've got a bunch of endpoints to test and I wonder what is the best approach to do it.
I thought about grouping tests for endpoints in separate .jmx files, for example:
Suppose that there are 2 endpoints: **A** with simple GET method and **B** that can serve GET, PUT, POST and DELETE requests. In this scenario I would create 2 .jmx files.

Any helpful links to some tutorials appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally people use [Test Fragments](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-manage-large-jmeter-scripts-jmeter-test-fragments) for organizing large JMeter scripts.

Depending on whether you want to keep the requests in a single .jmx script or separate you can use:

- [Module Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) - for re-using requests in the same scripts (i.e. to avoid [code duplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duplicate_code))
- [Include Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller) - to "pull" external .jmx script into the current one